# How can I create a JavaScript object in Internet Explorer from C++

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, com

I'm using an external C++ application to control Internet Explorer (version is 11, but that seems unimportant for this example). Part of this control is being able to run arbitrary JavaScript in the browser's context. To enable that control, I'd like to be able to create a JavaScript object (or array, or function, etc.), represented by an appropriate `IDispatch` variant, that I can use in subsequent script calls. There are some [examples online](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/88753/Creating-JavaScript-arrays-and-other-objects-from), including some [from Microsoft](https://github.com/Microsoft/IEDiagnosticsAdapter), that would indicate such a thing *should* be possible, by finding and invoking the Object constructor.

Below is some sample code, cribbed from the aforementioned examples, that *should* do the trick. However, when I execute the code, I get an E_INVALIDARG ("One or more arguments are invalid") HRESULT returned. What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix the issue?

```
// Example assumes that you're using an ATL project which give access to
// the "CCom" wrapper classes, and that you have the ability to retrieve
// an IHTMLDocument2 object pointer.
int CreateJavaScriptObject(IHTMLDocument2* script_engine_host, CComVariant* created_object) {
  // NOTE: Proper return code checking and error handling
  // has been omitted for brevity
  int status_code = 0;
  CComPtr<IDispatch> script_dispatch;
  HRESULT hr = script_engine_host->get_Script(&script_dispatch);
  CComPtr<IDispatchEx> script_engine;
  hr = script_dispatch->QueryInterface<IDispatchEx>(&script_engine);

  // Create the variables we need
  DISPPARAMS no_arguments_dispatch_params = { NULL, NULL, 0, 0 };
  CComVariant created_javascript_object;
  DISPID dispatch_id;

  // Find the javascript object using the IDispatchEx of the script engine
  std::wstring item_type = L"Object";
  CComBSTR name(item_type.c_str());
  hr = script_engine->GetDispID(name, 0, &dispatch_id);

  // Create the jscript object by calling its constructor
  // The below InvokeEx call returns E_INVALIDARG in this case
  hr = script_engine->InvokeEx(dispatch_id,
                               LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT,
                               DISPATCH_CONSTRUCT,
                               &no_arguments_dispatch_params,
                               &created_javascript_object,
                               NULL,
                               NULL);

  *created_object = created_javascript_object;
  return status_code;
}
```

Potential answerers desiring a fully compilable solution can find a version of the above code in a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/jimevans/JSObjectCreator). The repo includes a Visual Studio 2017 solution that creates a console application which will reproduce the issue, including launching Internet Explorer and obtaining a reference to the required `IHTMLDocument2` object. Note that the version in the repo has somewhat more complete error handling than the above sample, in which it was omitted for brevity.

Comment: Have you tried DISPATCH_METHOD instead of DISPATCH_CONSTRUCT? It returns something, but I'm not sure that's what you're looking for

Comment: Which call returns E_INVALIDARG?

Comment: @selalerer The call immediately below the comment that says “The below InvokeEx call returns E_INVALIDARG”

Comment: @JimEvans First thing I'd try is to put a `CComVariant` array in `no_arguments_dispatch_params` first field (doesn't matter what's in it since you put 0 in the count field anyway) and see if that works

Comment: @selalerer Thanks for the suggestion, but I’d previously tried that to no effect.